# JavaScript - Input BUTTON hide - not working

Tags: javascript

```
<input id="btnupdate" type="button" value="Update" onclick="update()"/>
<img id="loadupdate" src="http://localhost/connectu/styles/images/load_big.gif">
```

This code is returned by and PHP script in response to AJAX request. The update() function contains the code to hide the button and the image.

```
document.getElementById('btnupdate').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('loadupdate').style.display='none';
```

The update() function is in the native file. But the problem is, image gets hidden but not button.
I tried FIREBUG. No javascript errors.

Comment: What's with all the ``\`` in your HTML?

Comment: @FelixKling: I assume it's to break the " in his PHP script?

Comment: was in rush.. just copied it from the PHP file..

Comment: @Matthias: You mean escaping? Yeah probably... Raj: Don't `echo` HTML, it makes it hard to maintain if you have your HTML in PHP strings.

Comment: Escaping, that's indeed the word I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible you have more elements with `id='btnupdate'`?

Comment: i tried `document.getElementById('btnupdate').style.display='none';` in Firebug Console. It worked there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be `style.display`:

```
function update(){
    document.getElementById('btnupdate').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('loadupdate').style.display='none';
}
```

## [SEE IT'S WORKING](http://jsfiddle.net/sepny/)

Comment: the thing was.. I was HIDING the button UNTIL an RESPONSE is recieved.. Since, I was testing in local server, the response was fast enough no to see the HIDING effect..

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
 document.getElementById('btnupdate').style.display='none';
```

That should work